# Обновление ICU на PHP7

Tags: php, ubuntu, unicode

Подскажите, какие есть способы обновить ICU до актуальной версии на PHP7 на Ubuntu 14.04?
Ставил php7 из ppa репозитория ondrej. Пытался обновить ICU через pecl, но для 7 версии этот способ не работает. Получается выход только один - компилировать PHP из исходников и указывать icu вручную? Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: удалось как-то решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После долгих поисков я пришел к выводу что проще всего скомпилировать intl из репозитория php.

Ниже привожу мой пример для icu5.8.1 который ставится в /opt/icu5c на php-7.0.8. Для других версий нужно изменить пути к файлам соответсвенно.

```
sudo su    

#Install ICU
wget http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/58.1/icu4c-58_1-src.tgz
tar zxvf icu4c-58_1-src.tgz
cd icu/source
./configure --prefix=/opt/icu5c && make && make install

#Install intl.so from php source
cd ../..
wget https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/php-7.0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf php-7.0.8.tar.gz
cd php-src-php-7.0.8/ext/intl

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/icu5c/lib
phpize
./configure --enable-intl --with-icu-dir=/opt/icu5c
make
make install

#Activate extension (cli and fpm)
echo "extension=intl.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/intl.ini
ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/intl.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/intl.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-intl.ini
```

Comment: Замечу, что этот способ работает с ICU 58.2, но не работает с ICU 59.1 (проверено на своём опыте, выдаёт ошибки компиляции Си, использовался компилятор g++ 4.8.4 в Ubuntu). После установки убедитесь, что у вас активирована правильная версия icu в intl: `php -r "echo INTL_ICU_VERSION;"`, если не совпадает с версией ICU - снесите стандартный пакет php*-intl и повторите последний make install (который для сборки intl)

Answer (score 1):

Для тех у кого при команде make выдаются ошибки для ICU версии >=59.1, как у комментария @Arkemlar, мне помогли следующие флаги для компилятора

```
make CXXFLAGS="-g -std=c++11"
```

Комментом не смог добавить, из за репутации инфу